# Why do we need parameter(s) in a method(if it involves giving parameter), I mean what does a parameter do?

Tags: java, parameters

When we say

```
public static void task(int number)
{
      (you can give any example)
}
```

what is the function of parameter there ? I understand that when we give task.subtring(0,5) here the parameters are telling us the place value of the character. How does it work in "int"..

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. This parameter could be used for anything inside the function; its function will depend on what `task(int)` does. Also, what do you mean by `task.substring(0,5)`? Task is a method, you can't use the dot operator on it.

Comment: Hi,I was just showing that i understand the use of parameter in a substring. But parameters declared with "int", I am not clear with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are confused about the general idea of parameters, they are a message you pass to a method. Think of a method or a function for that matter as a labeled block of code the you can execute somewhere else using that label. Now, parameters are a way of giving a different input to that block of code. They are variables that get used inside that block of code and that you can set from outside of it by passing in a different value when you use that label. For example, I can pass an int (integer number) to a method that multiplies it by 2 and returns the result:

```
int multiplyBy2(int number){
     return number*2;}
```

Now, I can pass different numbers into that method and get different outputs. What could be confusing about that method you've shown is that it doesn't return a value and can't access class fields, so it might seem useless. However, that method can be doing a lot of other stuff with that integer. A few examples: the method can be printing some string to the screen that changes based on the integer, it could be writing to a file, it could be modifying static fields, and many other possible tasks.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you posted you would pass in the value of a single `int`; maybe to get a single character, maybe to read a specific line from a file; anything that needs that single `int`. In the example you understand there are two `int` parameters.

Comment: @Garry It will be 10. That's like asking what `x` does in a formula (any formula). It's a value.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is for the idea of parameters at all, aren't you? Parameters make methods more dynamic. for example you want to add a number to an existing int in an object. you will do it in this way (it is only a part of a class):

```
int all;
....
public void add(int i){
    all += i;
}
```

Comment: you mean that parameter will have the value I will pass into it. So why dont we directly assign value into instance variables ?

Comment: yeah it is idea of parameters... I am trying to be clear with.

Comment: So if you don't know how high the value will be. For example if you count all people in a room. When you begin counting you don't know how many people are in the room. So you have to make the method dynamic